# How to protect threads (of my process) from termination

Tags: c#, multithreading, security, winapi

I have written a Windows service that does a critical job.
My program has 5 threads that do a critical job and I don't want them to be terminated.

I use process hacker , in threads tab I can terminate any of the 5 thread without causing the whole program to get terminated (because programs are just container)
and the critical job is not done when user or a hacker (my program is a security program and users may want to make it not work) terminates one the  threads (i resume the thread if they get suspended  but have no strategy  preventing or fixing termination of thread)

How can I protect those 5 threads from termination?
(I've made the program itself critical but is does have no value when thread can be easily terminated)

Comment: If a user has permission to kill threads then, not surprisingly, they can kill threads and there's very little you can do to prevent this. Why not create a proper Windows service that will auto-restart if killed?

Comment: If the attacker can terminate your threads then they can just stop the service.

Comment: Like Eric Lippert said: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968581/how-to-prevent-an-app-from-being-killed-in-task-manager#comment24507766_16968581

Comment: Rather than giving your users security permissions to do things that you don't want them to do, and then writing a program running with equal permissions to try to stop them, you should *not actually give the user permissions to do things you don't want them to be able to do*.  The security system is there for a reason, use it.

Comment: I will not kill the thread. I will first suspend it, then freeze it. Your critical job will not be done.

Comment: tadman
my service auto starts if terminated (even it has critical flag do termiating will result in bsod  )
but problem is  killing some of the threads does not terminate the whole  process so i doesn't get terminated and restarted

Comment: Servy : it's the question

Comment: Servy  :how can i deny the user from being able to terminate one threads of my process

Comment: @emaditaj It's an impossible problem.  Impossible by definition.  No matter what you try to do, it will always be defeatable.  You need to use a suitable solution to your problem, one that actually is capable of solving it, and that's to not actually give users security permissions to do things you don't want them to be able to do.

Comment: You've really got this backwards. Privileged users can do privileged acts. Don't worry about that. Let the security system do its job.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because trying to fight the system instead of applying its security infrastructure is not a practical software engineering problem. Nor a practical programming problem.

Comment: This is not a reasonable requirement:(

Comment: found a solution and added as a answer 
i thank all of you for spending your time for helping me

Comment: Thomas Weller : i have a watch dog process that resumes every 1sec

Comment: can i ask why this question is getting down votes ??
you guys think this is not a problem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

First let me **explain** how I achieved this:

I made **2 watchdog threads** that the first one **recreates** the 5 threads and WatchDogThread2 when terminated and the second one does the same to **watchdog 1** (*this took me to long because of `Thread.IsAlive` was always returning true even when the thread was terminated finally used `Thread.Join()` and join was working*).

When one of the watchdog threads are running after a **termination**, it is **recreating** the lost one. But after 10-30 seconds and **exception** was thrown in a part that had no relation to watchdogs.

*I retried it for many times and did some debugging.*

After 30-50 tries and edit I saw that this **exception** is thrown in **random parts** of code not only the **particular part**.

So I started researching about the **exception**

```
ExecutionEngineException
```

I found out that CRL throws this when something in the code has **gone wrong**.
First, I thought that this issue is coused by one of the **watchdogs** so I changed them a few times but the **error** was still there (*just the time until it was thrown changed a little bit*).
So I **removed** them completely and started the program and terminated one the 5 thread.
This time **nothing** happened 
 
I did this for a few more times with some edits and saw this exception happens **when not using watchdogs**, too. *The exception came after 2-3 min instead of 10-30 seconds with the watchdogs*.
I researched again and Microsoft wrote on MSDN that this was happening sometimes if a **Garbage Collection was done**. I **disabled** the Garbage Collation and recieved no longer the exception.
I wrote another thread that forced Garbage to collate every **0.5 second** and saw after a thread is terminated the program received `ExecutionEngineException` and crashed.
This was the **solution** for garbage collation so the entire process crashes and restarts / BSOD happens.

---

#### Final Solution

If a thread is *terminated* and garbage collection triggers, then CRL throws `ExecutionEngineException`.
Just do a *manual garbage collation* every 0.5 sec so the program will crash and restart.

#### Code:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(delegate () {  
    while (true) { 
        System.GC.Collect(); 
        Thread.Sleep(500); 
    } 
}); 

t1.Start();
```

*You can start two of those threads for more security (if the user terminates `t1`, garbage collection will be triggered after 0-10 mins and in this time he will do whatever you want).*

Comment: 500 ms is **loads** of time for an attacker to terminate your watchdog thread, before it even gets a chance to start its sentinel. In particular, since you rely (unduly, at that, too) on exceptions. Any debugger can be set up to break, when an exception is raised. This is not a solution. As an aside, I don't know what a *"CRL"* is.

Comment: crl=Common Language Runtime
.net code is translated to crl at first 
ExecutionEngineException  is uncatchable (atleast with visual stdio debugger and try{}catch(Exception e){} that ii've tried

500ms may be enough for and auto written tool for spectioally terminating my software but i''m not considering prenvet that i wated to prevent manuall attams with tools like process hacker 
an attacker that writes a tool for this can bypas any protection i consider 
that's not my aim

Comment: The Common Language Runtime is abbreviated as CLR, not CRL. I'd comment on the rest of your comment, but am unable to understand any of it, due to complete lack of punctuation.